# validate radio button with parsley.js

Tags: jquery, html, validation, parsley.js

I am trying to validate radio button with parsley.js. Below is the code I am trying to use

```
  <p id="registration_field_custom2" class="onefield registration_field_custom2">
  <span class="doyou">
  <span class="text">etc etc etc etc ?</span>
    <input type="radio" name="custom2" value="Yes" id="custom2_yes" 
        data-required="true" 
        data-error-container="#submitDetails .error6" 
        data-error-message ="Please chose either yes or no"
    />
    <label for="custom2_yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="custom2" value="No" id="custom2_no"  
    />
    <label for="custom2_no">No</label>     
  </span>
  </p>
```

However, no matter whether I chose yes or no, it still is looking for data required for both. I just want user to be able to chose either yes or no... how Do I do that with parsley.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for radio input and checkbox is special case, in stead of using the the data-required , you should use the data-mincheck to ensure at least one of the option is checked.

Answer (score 17):

To validate radio button in Parsley, all you need to do is just use
- data-required="true". You don't need to use data-mincheck for radio button. As the radio buttons have the same names, parsley automatically recognises that they are in the same group. 
There is good example in the Parsley documentation: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html

Example:

```
<input id="radio-required" class="parsley-validated" type="radio" data-required="true" value="foo" name="radiorequired">
<input id="radio-required2" type="radio" value="bar" name="radiorequired">
```

Comment: This should be chosen answer. Thanks for the code sample

Answer (score -2):

data-mincheck   works for checkbox validation.

data-parsley-required="true"  works  for  option validation

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)